# Should we accept a tag-wiki edit made by a corporate employee?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, editing-help

I found an edit obviously made by a MS employee. This corporate edit is not false, but feel a lot like a PR move. In one hand, the source is trusthworthy but not so neutral.

[image: screeshot of queue]

As far as I know, we are not here to sell products. How should we handle this kind of case? Should we allow corporate edit?

- [Link to the tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azuresphere/info): [azuresphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuresphere)
- [Link to the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20650532)

Comment: I think that edits should be judged on merit, not according to who made them.

Comment: It does remove the reference to "Linux based"... which is a bit pr-weazily. I would add that back.

Comment: Just judge the edit by its content first, you can ratchet the critical eye up a bit when you want.  I personally think he did it wrong, the excerpt was already short and snappy, this should have been entered as the wiki.

Comment: @HansPassant - reading the content of the proposed revision, though, it sounds like the original tag wiki only described one of 2-3 components that fall under the "Azure Sphere" umbrella. I feel like snappiness shouldn't take precedence over completeness/accuracy.

Comment: in what sense is it "not neutral"? It looks like a fact based description made by someone likely a SME. It is not promotional.

Comment: @SamHanley But the edit isn't really useful as usage guidance, which is what's supposed to go in that section.

Comment: [What in the name of...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3E9A.png)? Welcome to Stack Overflow, you are obviously new here...

Comment: @Camilo See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372906/new-contributor-should-reflect-main-sites-not-meta-sites)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto first question in meta. be gentle ^^

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We should judge any edit based on its merits. The source of the edit is not relevant, as long as the information is correct and it's a good excerpt.

That being said, this edit broadens the tag (to apparently 3 distinct entities), and doesn't provide much guidance for how to use it. Questions about a *security service* might just be off-topic for SO.

I'd be prone to reject this edit, as it adds ambiguity, but will let the community decide.

Comment: It might be worth it to break this up into two tags (one for mcu & one for OS) if there start to be enough questions - currently it stands at 2 (1: MCU & 1: Security) so I don't think it is worth it to split yet.

Answer (score 5):

Even though there is an accepted answer, I just saw this and still feel this answer is needed:

The change is *okay*, just okay:

1. The original quote is a direct copy from wikipedia: [which is stated as not okay on the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/297125)
2. The new wording is based on [MS's own docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-microsoft-azure-sphere-secure-and-power-the-intelligent-edge/) by an MS employee - so less of a licensing issue (I assume as IANAL).
3. There are only 2 questions using this tag: One is about MCU and the other is about the Security Service (and should be closed as it is not about programming). Neither are about the SphereOS (which would be the Linux kernel mentioned in the previous description) but it is conceivable that there would be OS questions later.

Again, that makes it okay and at least better than the original tag description which was plagiarized and described the part of the system which people were not asking questions about. Now it could still be better because:

- Its still basically copied from MS so could do with some "in your own words" treatment by a user of the system.
- It really does describe an umbrella of three components so may just need to be split.

So if you can address those two then, yes edit the tag. If you cannot, don't just revert it to the old version.

Comment: "so no license problem" actually, there could be a license problem in the way that by posting on SE you agree to put your content as CC by-sa

Comment: @Braiam true..."less of a license problem" then? Its still only okay as both are still copies.

Comment: IANAL, but things aren't so simple.

Comment: If the text in the edit is copied, then the edit should be rejected as plagiarism. This should be the case for any edit (questions, answers, & tags). For tag edits, it's a specific rejection criteria. [Approving edits introducing plagiarism into tag excerpts/wikis is something for which the reviewer will, explicitly, receive a review-ban](/q/318288). We're specifically required to check for plagiarism when reviewing tag edits.

Comment: As to this edit, I'd be more comfortable with a bit more rewording, but, I'd consider it borderline, due primarily to the first sentence. While the first sentence is close to a copy, it's not quite. There are not that many ways to say what's there concisely, but it could have, and should have, been reworded a bit more. The second sentence is primarily a list of product names, which must be exact. There isn't a sentence on the Microsoft page you linked which is similar, so I wouldn't consider it copied from that source.

Comment: None of your points are related to a tag excerpt's purpose (tag usage guidance) which is the sole thing that matters. So they are all spectacularly irrelevant.

Comment: Copyright perspective is the last thing you should consider when deciding on an edit. [Short phrases are not copyrightable outright](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/2003/09/09/copyright_protection_for_short/), and [longer excerpts fall under fair use for our purposes](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Wikiquote:Copyrights#Copyrights_and_quotations). What is much more important, a full paragraph ripped out of somewhere most likely _doesn't fit the purposes of a tag excerpt_ so it has to be adapted anyway.