# Should the New Contributor indicator treat meta sites as separate sites?

Tags: discussion, new-contributor-indicator

Currently, you can have 10k rep and hundreds of questions and answers on the main site, but if you've never made a meta post you'll still be marked as a New Contributor on the meta site.

[image: dude with 7.8k rep, hundreds of answers and still a New Contributor]

When I saw this I was immediately sure it was a bug, but upon further investigation I realised it's by design. And I understand the reasoning: if they've never posted on meta, they are indeed a new contributor to the site.

However it still felt *wrong* every time I saw it. It took me a minute to put my finger on why, but now it's obvious. The New Contributor indicator is to help us be more welcoming to the new user, not the other way around. It does *nothing at all* to help the new user do a better job of posting quality content. And if they've already gained 7.8k rep that means they've already done a been through a *tonne* of questions and/or answers (in this case, hundreds of answers). Surely by this point the user will be *well and truly* acquainted with our sites.

I'm aware of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372906/2288578), which suggests the indicator shouldn't be shown in cases like this. While I completely agree, that's not the point of my question. I want to know how everyone else feels about this, bearing in mind my point that it doesn't seem to make sense for meta sites to be treated separately from the main sites with regards to the New Contributor indicator.

Thoughts?

Comment: Considering the voting on the answer there, I'm not sure that there's much disagreement. Is there a reason to have a second discussion? It might be better for you to answer that question with the information you include here as a competing answer.

Comment: @Catija To be completely honest I hadn't thought of providing an answer to the other question, however my goal here to was to gather feedback on whether other people agreed with me, bearing in mind the additional point I brought up. The other question is purely one-sided, and doesn't promote discussion. I'm very surprised this was closed as a dupe. It's similar but most certainly not the same. And of course, whether it's my fault or not, having my question closed before anyone can respond always stings. I did put a lot of effort in, after all. I think I finally understand "be welcoming"... :(

Comment: The other question has the discussion tag (despite reading like a feature request) and writing answers that add support to existing discussion questions *is* actually a valid type of answer on meta. You can absolutely still get feedback on whether people agree with you by writing an answer. And duplicate closures on meta are a bit more broad than they are on the main site for that purpose. It serves the community better to have a single conversion about something than to have several near-identical ones going on at once.

Comment: I'm not sure how having this closed as a duplicate is unwelcoming. Being welcoming is a matter of kindly helping users understand how the system works while still upholding the guidelines and expectations of the system. Duplicate questions can be well-researched and clearly written. If you do consider writing an answer, I strongly encourage you to consider the existing answer on that question - the points it makes. There's a reason it's so highly regarded. Meta is hard. Having 10K or 100K on main doesn't mean you'll be an immediate success on meta... it takes effort to learn how meta works.

Comment: @Catija Ah, no I didn't say it was unwelcoming (it's not really welcoming _or_ unwelcoming), I said I understood the point of "be welcoming". It makes sense now. I haven't had something shut down so hard in a while so I'd forgotten what it feels like. It might be entirely my fault and I should know better, but even the gentlest of question closes still hits hard. It feels like no one gave it a chance, and everyone's an uncaring jerk. I was just commenting really :) I found it interesting that all these feeling and thoughts when through my head. I was surprised to realise it felt _unwelcoming_.

Comment: My point being, if people had been genuinely unwelcoming _on top of_ the question being closed, I would probably have been distinctly upset and angry, and if I were new I definitely wouldn't want to come back. Again, I just found it interesting :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. It's the sort of thing we're really interested in hearing and why we're trying to change things to make them easier to bear. We have been running on a lot of assumptions based on our knowledge and acceptance of the system and what it's like, so it's pretty near impossible to see what being new feels like and how confusing it can be. Having moments of empathy are sometimes enlightening.

Comment: @Clonkex, but after having all this conversation, do you still believe the question is wrongly closed as a duplicate? As one of the "uncaring jerks" who VTC, I do believe that the this question is a clear duplicate of that one, and that no useful discussion could have happened on this one that couldn't have happened there. Don't you agree?

Comment: @yivi Initially I believed it was wrongly closed, but then Catjita pointed out that meta is actually _more_ strict than main (I thought it would be the other way around, but it makes sense that we want discussions in one place). Please don't take offence at my comment on "uncaring jerks". That was how it felt emotionally, not rationally. And no, I don't agree that this is a clear duplicate, but I do believe it's acceptable that it was closed as a dupe. I think it was more likely that the discussion I wanted would happen here, but I'm ok with how it turned out.

Comment: Since you still believe this is not a clear dupe: Why do you believe this question is not a duplicate of that one? In which way it is a different discussion that prompts different answers?

Comment: I think that delving deeper in this is important, since I think that most of the abrassive emotional response comes from not some newer users not yet knowing how the different mechanisms of the site work, and more experienced users having the (probably wrong) expectations of other users understanding what their actions means. E.g., to me, if you understood what closing as a dupe meant, there should be no way you'd feel emotionally challenged by a closure, to the point you felt you were being mistreated by a group of... well, what you said.

Comment: I'm here for the freehand amoeba.

Comment: @yivi I believe it's not a clear dupe because the goal was to get people to give feedback after having been offered arguments for both sides. In the other post, respondents were required to come up with reasons against having the separated indicator themselves, which no one has yet done (so it's heavily biased). I'm also well aware of what closing as a dupe means, but that's exactly the problem. I felt it was obviously not a dupe (especially since I very specifically pointed out _how_ it wasn't a dupe in the question) so I was immediately frustrated and upset that it was closed so quickly.

Comment: @Will I'm actually relieved that someone finally acknowledged it.